# How can I validate acceptance of one boolean or another boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid

I need to validate that one boolean or another boolean is accepted in a form.

I tried

```
validates_acceptance_of :seller_accepted || :buyer_accepted
```

but this does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails validators are metaprogramming macros. The are read in when the class is evaluated. They add a list a validation rules (callbacks) to be run when `valid?` is called to the class.

This is why you have to use the `if` and `unless` options with either a lambda, proc or a symbol which is actually called when the instance is validated.

Thats one of the reasons your code will not work. Using an `if` or `unless` condition does not work here either - Rails would add and error to `seller_accepted` before it evaluates `if: :buyer_accepted`.

In this case it the cleanest way to solve it may be to create a custom validation method:

```
validate :one_of_two_accepted

def one_of_two_accepted
  unless acceptable?(seller_accepted) || acceptable?(buyer_accepted)
    errors.add(:seller_accepted, "Must accept buyer or seller.")
  end
end

def acceptable?(val)
  ['1', true, 'yes'].include?(val)
end
```

The `acceptable?` method simulates the typecasting done by `validates_acceptance_of`.

## Edit.

This is complete, minimal, verified example:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :seller_accepted
  attr_accessor :buyer_accepted

  validate :one_of_two_accepted

  def acceptable?(val)
    ['1', true].include?(val)
  end

  def one_of_two_accepted
    unless acceptable?(seller_accepted) || acceptable?(buyer_accepted)
      errors.add(:seller_accepted, "Must accept buyer or seller.")
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Thing, type: :model do

  let(:thing) { Thing.new }

  describe 'acceptable?' do
    it "accepts '1'" do
      expect(thing.acceptable?('1')).to be_truthy
    end

    it "accepts 'true' " do
      expect(thing.acceptable?(true)).to be_truthy
    end

    it "rejects others" do
      expect(thing.acceptable?('gobbeligook')).to be_falsy
      expect(thing.acceptable?('no')).to be_falsy
      expect(thing.acceptable?(nil)).to be_falsy
      expect(thing.acceptable?(0)).to be_falsy
    end
  end

  describe 'custom validation' do
    it 'is invalid if neither seller or buyer is accepted' do
        expect(thing.valid?).to be_falsy
        expect(thing.errors[:seller_accepted]).to include "Must accept buyer or seller."
    end

    it 'is valid if seller_accepted' do
      thing.seller_accepted = true
      thing.valid?
      expect(thing.errors).to_not have_key :seller_accepted
    end

    it 'is valid if buyer_accepted' do
      thing.buyer_accepted = true
      thing.valid?
      expect(thing.errors).to_not have_key :seller_accepted
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Max, I will try shortly when I'm in front of my computer. Why did you remove your answer from the question yesterday?

Comment: I did'nt have the time / energy to edit it so that it answered the question properly.

Comment: Oh ok i thought maybe i had said something to offend. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: so i have been working with the acceptable? method but it is returning nil instead of true or false even though i know my val = true. Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Thats strange, includes? Returns true/false

Comment: Do you know of any documentation on includes? I am having trouble finding it

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it should be `include?`. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84811/discussion-between-supremea-and-max).